# How to debug asp.net core async method using Source Link?

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-core, async-await, sourcelink

I am trying to debug asp.net core internals to see what is going on under the hood.

I set up .net core debugging in VS Code according to this article: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Debugging-into-the-.NET-Framework-itself

Now I get .net core sources automatically while debugging and can step into methods, **but not async ones**. Since I have no source code at hand (it loads on the fly from somewhere) I cannot set a breakpoint in an async method to make debugger stop there.

I have the following controller method. How can I step into `HttpContext.SignInAsync(...)` method in VS Code debugger?

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    ...
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
    ...
}
```

**Update #1**

Same thing for Visual Studio 2019. So it does not matter if I use VS Code or VS 2019.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. When stepping into an async method, the debugger steps into the internal state machine and not the method itself.